# replace or remove characters and then cast to decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to remove or replace an unwanted haracter `(%)` wich is in the end of a string and thyen to cast the string to a decimal, because I need to get the **sum** of 2 fields named `discount1` and `discount2`

The last combination I tried is:

```
replace ((p16.pa_value,'%','')CAST (p16.pa_value AS DECIMAL (3,0))) as discount2,
```

It seems to be super wrong as the `CAST` is inside of the `replace` statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
CAST (replace (p16.pa_value,'%','') AS DECIMAL (3,0)) as discount2
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't know why do you have three digits after decimal: `DECIMAL (3,0)` because if you convert to decimal it should be: decimal (10; how many zeros after ,) - [more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258271%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Try this:

```
(cast(replace(p16.pa_value, '%','')  as decimal (10,2))) as discount
```