# Can't get result after casting 2 strings to float if the one string is null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This question is regarding one of my previous questions. You can find it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340190/replace-or-remove-characters-and-then-cast-to-decimal)

I am trying to get the summary of 2 strings.
What I managed so far is:

```
CAST (replace((replace (p8.pa_value,'%','')),' ','') AS float (3,0)) +
CAST (replace((replace (p9.pa_value,'%','')),' ','') AS float (3,0)) as total_discount
```

The problem is that when the `p9.pa_value` or `p8.pa_value` is **null**(empty) the sum result is also **null**

Is there a way to get the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to substitute a `NULL` value with something else (say, an empty string), you can use `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE(CAST (replace((replace (p8.pa_value,'%','')),' ','') AS float (3,0)),'') +
COALESCE(CAST (replace((replace (p9.pa_value,'%','')),' ','') AS float (3,0)),'') as total_discount
```

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) returns the first non-null expression from its arguments. You can supply as many arguments as you like. (There is an Transact-SQL only function called `ISNULL` that is similar. I'd usually recommend `COALESCE` though, since it's standard SQL, takes multiple arguments, and performs correct type precedence)

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot! I had no idea about `COALESCE`

Answer (score 1):

As you noted; Any operation on a NULL value results in NULL.  So when one of the pa_value is NULL the result is NULL as well.

[ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) can be used to check for and convert NULL values to some other value of your choice. So query can be re-written like:

```
ISNULL(CAST (replace((replace (p8.pa_value,'%','')),' ','') AS float (3,0)), 0.0) +
ISNULL(CAST (replace((replace (p9.pa_value,'%','')),' ','') AS float (3,0)), 0.0) as total_discount
```